# UITableViewCell's contentView has different width when calling in heightForRowAtIndexPath:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I am trying to calculate the height of a table view cell that is layout using auto layout. As this has to be compatible to iOS7 as well, I need to return a valid height for `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

What I am doing is the following:

```
if (self.userRatingsAbbreviatedTextCell == nil) {
    self.userRatingsAbbreviatedTextCell = [[UserRatingsAbbreviatedTextCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
}
[self.userRatingsAbbreviatedTextCell prepareForReuse];
UserRating *rating = [self.paginationModel ratingAtIndex:reviewIndex];
[self.userRatingsAbbreviatedTextCell configureCellForHotelUserRating:rating];
[self.userRatingsAbbreviatedTextCell layoutIfNeeded];

CGSize size = [self.userRatingsAbbreviatedTextCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
return size.height;
```

The cell has a disclosure indicator. When I ask the cell for its `contentView` width it is `296`. However in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` after dequeuing a cell, its `contentView` width is `289`, which is the size that is used for rendering. Has anybody experienced such issues? What do I need to do for the cell to set its `contentView` width correctly?

Comment: if the table is static you can get height from `super`

Comment: yet it is still broken... I have investigated this a bit more and have found that calling `_configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:` on the table view and passing it the cell resizes the content view to the correct size, yet as this is private API, that is not a fix for the issue...

Comment: Have you already seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights

Comment: Yes, this is the way we do our cell layouting, but the iOS7 compatible way is not working on iOS8 anymore as soon as there is a disclosure indicator or similar accessory view.

Comment: I don't get your answer, what is broken exactly and what are the results of view debugging ?

Comment: The results are the same that I posted in my original question: The size of the `contentView` is wrong when using a cell that has not been configured by the table view. The width is 296 instead of 289, which is the size when the cell is drawn by the table view.

Comment: I'd be interested in testing a small sample project, do you think it would be possible for you to prepare and share it ?

Comment: @A-Live I filed this as rdar and attached the following sample project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q367d5q6lfncf32/HeightCalculation.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the `contentView` being a different size than the `UITableViewCell`. May break some of `UITableViewCell`'s innate properties such as accessory views.

Override `UITableViewCell`'s `layoutSubviews` method in your cell class:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // force `contentView` to be the same size as `self` (it's typically 0.5pt smaller)
    CGRect contentViewFrame = self.contentView.frame;
    contentViewFrame.size = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.frame));
    self.contentView.frame = contentViewFrame;
}
```

In my case, the `contentView` was always `0.5` points smaller and it was causing problems when calculating the correct height for `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`. I would calculate the perfect height for the cell that wouldn't cause a `UILabel` to wrap but it would always cut off the last line since the height was `0.5` points too small.

My cell, for reference:

[image: Custom UITableViewCell XIB]